# How to find LINESTRINGs that touch in a begin/ending node

Tags: postgresql, postgis

In PostGIS you can intersect two geometries using:

```
geometry ST_Intersection (geometry geomA, geometry geomB);
```

In my case both geomA and geomB are `LINESTRING` so `ST_Intersection()` returns a `POINT` geometry.

I want to know if the intersection occurs in a begin/end node (the geometries touch) or in the middle (the geometries intersect).

I can compare the (Point.X, Point.Y) with each ending node:

- geomA.nodes(0) - geomA.nodes(len-1)
- geomB.nodes(0) - geomB.nodes(len-1)

But is very complex. And I would like a simple solution.

### There are 3 intersect cases.

> Example 1: Two lines in a "L" shape intersect in an end node on both lines on the bottom left.
>
> Example 2: Two lines in a "T" shape where the vertical line intersects in the middle of the horizontal line. In this case the vertical line end node touches a non-end node of the horizontal line.
>
> Example 3: Two lines in a "X" shape. Intersection point isn't an end node for either line.

For my problem I'm only interested in finding the touching scenario like Example 2.

### NOTE

This is the pseudo code I use now.

geomM, geomN Linestring
a, b, c, d, z Points. 
(a,b) begin/end node for geomM  `ST_StartPoint(geom) and ST_EndPoint(geom)`
(c,d) begin/end node for geomN
z = ST_Intersect(geomM, geomN)

```
SELECT geomM, geomN, z
FROM Table
WHERE 
         (A and not ( B or C or D))
     OR  (B and not ( A or C or D))
     OR  (C and not ( A or B or D))
     OR  (D and not ( A or B or C))
```

A, B, C, D replace ( a=z ) ( b=z ) ( c=z ) ( d=z )  
This mean one node {a,b,c,d} is equal to intersection z. But only one 
This return all "T" shape intersections.

Comment: If the "intersection" is at a starting or ending node of a `LINESTRING` with any intermediary point on another `LINESTRING`, then it is, topologically speaking, not an intersection but touching boundaries.

Comment: @Patrick sorry but I'm not familiar with topological lenguaje. I call it intersection because I use `ST_Intersect` to find the point. Is there a ST_Touch returning point?

Comment: `ST_Intersects()` returns a `boolean` to indicate if two geometries intersect, `ST_Intersection()` returns a `geometry` of the actual intersection. Your question is "if the intersection occurs in a begin/end node"; since the node is a `geometry` (of a `POINT`) that would give the answer you are looking for if it indeed touches another `LINESTRING`. But it will be a complex `WHERE` clause  however you approach it due to your constraints.

Answer (score 4):

You need the PostGIS function `ST_Touches()` [here](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Touches.html). The function returns `true` if the geometries touch on their boundaries, but `false` if they intersect. In terms of your examples, Example 1 and 2 return `true`, Example 3 returns `false`.

### Relaxed solution

To select the IDs of all pairs of touching `geometry(LINESTRING, xxx)` records from a single table use this:

```
SELECT x.id AS idA, y.id AS idB
FROM my_table x
JOIN my_table y ON ST_Touches(y.the_geom, x.the_geom)
WHERE x.id < y.id;
```

(The `WHERE` clause avoids duplicate results like `(132, 254)` and `(254, 132)`.)

Note that the linestrings can also touch on any of their non-node vertices. If you want to strictly follow Example 2 then you have to compare every point on every linestring against every point on all other linestrings, which is obviously going to be a very intensive operation. Example 2 is basically only feasible when you know that the linestrings are very short, preferably just straight lines.

### Strict solution, straight lines only

If all `LINESTRING`s are straight, i.e. composed of a starting and an ending node only, then this is your solution:

```
SELECT h.id AS touched, v.id AS touching, ST_Intersection(h.the_geom, v.the_geom) AS touch_point
FROM my_table h     -- "horizontal" T bar, being touched
JOIN my_table v ON  -- "vertical" T bar, touching
    (
      -- The "vertical" start node touches, but not on either of the "horizonal" nodes
      ST_Equals(ST_Intersection(h.the_geom, v.the_geom), ST_StartPoint(v.the_geom))
      AND NOT ST_Equals(ST_StartPoint(h.the_geom), ST_StartPoint(v.the_geom))
      AND NOT ST_Equals(ST_EndPoint(h.the_geom), ST_StartPoint(v.the_geom))
    ) OR (
      -- The "vertical" end node touches, but not on either of the "horizonal" nodes
      ST_Equals(ST_Intersection(h.the_geom, v.the_geom), ST_EndPoint(v.the_geom))
      AND NOT ST_Equals(ST_StartPoint(h.the_geom), ST_EndPoint(v.the_geom))
      AND NOT ST_Equals(ST_EndPoint(h.the_geom), ST_EndPoint(v.the_geom))
    );
```

All the requirements are checked in the `JOIN ON` clause. This will also return the location where the "vertical" bar of the T touches the "horizontal" bar. Note that the conditions are short-circuited when being evaluated and repeated calls to a function with the same input data are optimized to a single call.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Didn't know about the touch function. But doesn't solve my issue. I Include part of my code, it just check if exactly one begin/end node is equal to the intersection point. No really intensive but is very complicated where clausule.